# Jquery each and click event together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links on a page. One of the links has a class `selected` by default. When a user clicks on one of the links, then it becomes `selected` and the previous one gets deselected. I do it like this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

What I do not like about this is 1) nesting - it looks ugly 2) I'm not sure whether it is possible that the callback inside `each` is called after I do `addClass`. So, I need some style advise, some good practical solution.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. You may want to rephrase it.

Comment: try just `$("a").removeClass("selected")`

Comment: @ Will P. Yes, it works. This idea has just came to my mind. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify point 2 for you, it's not possible. Javascript is (mostly) synchronous, so unless you do something weird (like an Ajax call, or some other asynchronous call) things will be executed in order.

Comment: @DrunkWolf. So, even if I add some timer inside `each`, it will still be executed first? I mean its callback where I do `removeClass`?

Comment: If you do a timeout, it will skip it's execution and continue until the time comes around for the timeout to be executed, at which point it will be put in the back of the queue. So a timeout before removeclass, even a timeout 0, would give you problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use each. The following should do what you want (put it inside of your click):

```
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you, Peter!